# Winpcap packet forwarding. Java wrapper

Tags: java, forwarding, winpcap, arp, spoofing

I am trying to build a winpcap application capable of sniff traffic of a target host within a switch-based LAN.

To carry out this, I am trying to perform a arp spoofing. This way, messages between the target host and the getaway will be sent through me, and then I'll be able to sniff them.

I know how the spoofing works, what arp packets I must send and how to send them.
The **problem comes** with the forwarding stuff: By default, my machine is going to drop the packets upon arrival, because they’re not destined to my IP address.

I have read about IPEnableRouter Windows registry value, but I'd prefer some code to get it.

I have been using Java Wrapper libraries for WinPcap (jNetPcap、Jpcap) but I could use some other languaje.
Both computers have Windows Vista installed.

Answer (score 0):

> By default, my machine is going to drop the packets upon arrival, because they’re not destined to my IP address.

That *shouldn't* happen if you put the adapter into promiscuous mode.  Presumably the Java wrappers for WinPcap support promiscuous mode; the libpcap/WinPcap API `pcap_open_live()` does so and has done so since libpcap was first created.

This does mean that *your program* will have to do the forwarding, but, well, if you want to play networking games such as ARP spoofing, you may have to do a lot more networking stuff, such as packet forwarding, than you might want to.